# Extension de Firefox para modificar colores no corre

Tags: javascript, extensiones, firefox-webextensions

Intente hacer una extension a modo de prueba usando un tutorial, pero por alguna razón no funciona la parte de js

[Este es el tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3AQ5D2QFwc)

Yo hice todo el procedimiento de codigo igual, pero no se si hubo alguna actualización en Firefox que rompe el codigo javascript. Porque el html funciona.

Esto es lo que tengo en manifest.json

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Sepia",
    "version": "1.0",
  
    "description": "Gives everything a sepia like tone.",
  
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
        "js": ["content_script.js"]
          }
    ],

    "browser_action": {
      "browser_style": true,
      "default_icon": {
        "48": "sepia.png"
      },
      "default_title": "Sepia",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    
    "permissions": [
      "storage"
    ]
  }
```

Esto es lo que tengo en popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<style>

body{
 padding: 1em;
}

input{
 margin-left: 1em;
}


</style>


</head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"></meta>
<body>

    <label>Sepia Control
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" width="100">
    </label>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en popup.js, que agarra el valor actual del color

```
let input = document.querySelector('input'); //

input.addEventListener('change', e => setValue(e.target.value));

async function setValue(value){
    await browser.storage.local.set({value})
}

async function init(){
    let { value } = browser.local.storage.get('value');
    if(!value){
        value = 0;
    }

    input.value = value;
    setValue(value);

}

init().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Esto es lo que tengo en content_script.js, que es el codigo que deberia en teoria cambiar todo

```
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    document.body.appendChild(style);
    
    browser.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, area) => {
    
        if(area === 'local' && value in changes) {
            update(changes.value.NewValue);
        }
    });
    
    function update(value){
        style.innerText = 'html {filter: sepia($[value]%) !important }';
    
    }
    
    let style = document.createElement('style');
document.body.appendChild(style);

browser.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, area) => {

    if(area === 'local' && value in changes) {
        update(changes.value.NewValue);
    }
});

function update(value){
    style.innerText = 'html {filter: sepia($[value]%) !important }';

}

browser.storage.local.get('value').then(result => update(result.value));
```

Comment: Tutorial de hace 2 años y con los comentarios desactivados, creo que tiene todo lo que se necesita como para no fiarse de esa información. Esto es cuestión de ponerse a comprobar código hasta que se descubra que no está haciendo el trabajo o ver que error devuelve

Comment: No devuelve ningun error, el console.log parece no funcionar

Comment: En las extensiones únicamente funciona el `console.error()`